# git bundle not moving 'git tag' information

Tags: git, tags, git-bundle

I have a remote repo with tag names v3 and v4

```
$git tag
```

> v3
>
> v4

I created a bundle for this remote repo with..

```
git bundle create repo.bundle --all
```

When updating local repo with bundle information...

```
git pull 'path_to_bundle' branch_name_in_bundle

$git tag
```

does not! display

> v3
>
> v4

How can I pass tag info to the local repo ?

I tried `git bundle create repo.bundle --branches --tags`

with no success

Comment: Try `git pull --tags` + the bundle location and so on.

Comment: @Lasse A++++++++++++++++++ thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git fetch --tags 'path_to_bundle'
```