# Is it possible to include tags with git format-patch

Tags: git

git format-patch does not appear to include tags, either lightweight or annotated, in the final patch file.

Is that the case? If so, what do folks do to synchronize repositories that include tags using patch files?

Comment: Try git bundle. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49101839/7976758 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/66680244/7976758

Comment: Thanks @phd, bundle does indeed preserve the tags. We use exactly this for initial provisioning of a new remote repo but is not useful for ongoing synchronization.

Comment: @jplejacq but it's the right tool. If you need ongoing synchronization between two repos, use git itself, not emails. If you need to use emails, pidgeons carrying usb thumbdrives or tape archives, then git bundle is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

A tag is simply nothing that has anything to do with a patch. It's supposed to describe a *state* of your tree, not a *difference*.

So, no, that's neither possible nor sensible.

> If so, what do folks do to synchronize repositories that include tags using patch files?

You can't synchronize tags via email. The format-patch / send-email procedure is meant for *change communication*, not for release management, version tracking etc.